# Files "can not be copied to the iPad because they can not be played on the iPad"

Tags: itunes, ipad, pdf, data-transfer, file-transfer

I have added some PDFs on iTunes:

[image]

When I tried to drag the files into the Stephen's iPad on the left nav the following message appears:

[image]

I have tried the other PDFs and all result in the same error.

Why is it **so difficult** to simply copy PDFs to the iPad via usb??

Comment: Are you sure your iPad or settings aren't just messed up: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326923/how-to-install-ibooks-on-ipad ?

Comment: I think that iTunes for some reason recognized the PDFs as songs, and gives the warning that the PDF cannot be played.