# How to install iBooks on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, books

There is no `iBooks` on my iPad. I went to the iTunes AppStore and searched for `iBooks` and that showed anything and everything *but* that app.

So what is the correct way to use/install/download `iBooks` ?

Comment: What iPad and iOS versions are you using?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way might be to open your web browser on the iPad and open a link to a book.

That will take you to the store if you need the app and take you to the app if you just lost where the icon is installed.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/apple-watch-user-guide/id985786488

If that doesn't work, your iOS is a bit messed up and backing up your data and restoring the device would be the next step. More info at https://help.apple.com/ipad/11/

Comment: My iPad started becoming  unreliable soon after this: it would think the battery power were zero and not work.  I will check this out when/if I can spend more cycles on it.